# Vue Component Versioning, is something along these lines possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently import my component dynamically as they are needed, however if a lot of changes are required on a component, I would want to make a new version of it, however it would still be the same component in a way.

I have the following within my app.js:

```
Vue.component( 'favourites-panel', () => import('./components/Favourites/Panel.vue' );
```

Can I change the above to something like this and get the **version** from the `prop`? Obviously this is theoretical code!

```
Vue.component( 'favourites-panel', (e) => import('./components/Favourites/Panel' + e.version + '.vue' );
```

This is how i'm calling my component:

```
<favourites-panel version="1"></favourites-panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible "versioning" a component using the props object.
First of all, you need to understand what you are doing:  `Vue.component` is a function to load globally all the components you want. You can pass an absolute path or if required, a promise.
In this case, you want to load your component asynchronously and the statement import, return a Promise. If you inspect the `e` property you'll see that is the resolve callback.
Writing:

```
Vue.component( 'favourites-panel', () => import('./components/Favourites/Panel.vue' );
```

or:

```
Vue.component('favourites-panel', function (resolve) {
  require(['./components/Favourites/Panel.vue'], resolve)
})
```

It's the same thing, both returns a Promise object.
For solving your problem you can add an [environment variable](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) and then load the 
component according to the value of that particular environment variable.

Comment: Damn, see I can't use an environment variable as this would be per client and per component.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is entirely the wrong approach to both source control and dependency management. You should instead be creating NPM modules of your component(s) and then if for some reason you need to use an old one again you can `npm install` the old version.

Comment: Do you have any reason for this? As If even need a slight modification, with npm it won't be possible at all